# Topological structure of the dunce hat

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, covering-spaces, fundamental-groups

I'm trying to get an idea on how the [dunce hat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dunce_hat_(topology)) works. I'd like to compute $\pi_1$, $H_n$, and its universal covering space. Any ideas on what these will look like?

Answer (score 5):

The wikipedia page mentions that it is contractible. It follows that $\pi_1$ is trivial and $H_0\cong \mathbb{Z}$ and $H_i=0$ for $i\not=0$. The universal cover is the space itself.

Comment: Also, is the fact that it is its own universal cover follow from the fact that the space is simply connected?

Comment: yes, that is true